# Agresso payment creation via acrbatchinput

Tags: erp

We're attempting to generate payments in an Agresso 5.5 system. The mechanism we've been told to use is to write new payment data into table acrbatchinput where it will be picked up and processed by a regular job running in agrbibat.dll. We have code that worked on a previous version of Agresso but following the upgrade our payments get rejected by the agrbibat job. Sometimes it generates useful messages in the log, sometimes it doesn't, and working through failures without good information is becoming a bit of a slog.

Is there some documentation we're missing? In particular it would be useful to have a full list of validation rules the job is using so we can implement these ourselves rather than trying to infer them from the log. I can't find any - there's not a lot for acrbatchinput on Google. Does this list or some other documentation exist? Is agribibat something easily decompilable, e.g. .NET?

Thanks. The test system we have is running against Oracle on Solaris with the Agresso jobs hosted on Windows. We have limited access to the Oracle and Agresso systems because (I think!) the same Oracle server is hosting the live payment system, but I could probably talk finance into giving us agrbibat.dll if that might help. We're unlikely to get enough access to their servers to debug it in place.

---

It turns out that our problem is partly because the new test system we've been given access to wasn't set up correctly, so we might be able to progress this without extra information - we're waiting on the financial team here for input.

However we're still interested in acrbatchinput or agrbibat documentation or information. You've missed the bounty I set but ticks, votes and gratitude still available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an ancient old question, but here's my response anyway for anyone else that finds it.

The only documentation is the usual Agresso help files from within the desktop client. Meaningful information is only gleaned through trial and error, however!

The required fields differs depending on whether a given record is a GL, AP/AR or tax transaction. (That much is, at least, explained in the help).

In addition to using the log file, it's often helpful to look at GL07's report output for errors.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm no longer working on that project (or with Agresso) but that rings true. My colleague at the time did have the desktop client though. Short of any better ideas you can have the tick!